# Table Layout type in Rikulo

Tags: rikulo

On the Rikulo documentation I see at [Attributes of Layout and Profile](http://docs.rikulo.org/ui/latest/Layouts/Fundamentals/Attributes_of_Layout_and_Profile.html) for sometime now that the layout are of the following types:

- none
- linear
- stack
- tiles
- table

Is there any timeline for the table layout to come on stream?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, we don't have any plan to deliver both tiles and table layout yet. You are welcome to contribute one:)